# Error in loop object not found in R - values column name

Tags: r, loops, assign

I have a database which has 16 columns and several rows. Here an example of the data:

```
structure(list(breed = c("1", "1", "1"), id = c(1,6,12), 
               `01_OARCP49_1` = c(100L, 80L, 82L), 
               `01_OARCP49_2` = c(112L,82L, 114L), 
               `02_FCB11_1` = c(122L, 120L, 122L),
               `02_FCB11_2` = c(122L,120L, 132L), 
               `04_FCB304_1` = c(170L, 162L, 162L),
               `04_FCB304_2` = c(170L,164L, 170L), 
               `05_INRA063_1` = c(175L, 175L, 169L),
               `05_INRA063_2` = c(179L,89L, 201L), 
               `06_MAF214_1` = c(191L, 189L, 191L), 
               `06_MAF214_2` = c(191L,191L, 225L),
               `07_CSRD247_1` = c(223L, 223L, 213L),
               `07_CSRD247_2` = c(227L, 239L, 227L), 
               `08_HSC_1` = c(NA, 273L, 273L), 
               `08_HSC_2` = c(NA, 273L, 275L)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -3L),
          class = c("data.table", "data.frame")) ->df
```

I'm trying to run a **loop** to: 1) calculate a **frequency table** to get the most common value per **each pair of columns** from column 3 till column 16 (e.g. frequency among: 01_OARCP49_1,01_OARCP49_2 and so forth) and then 2) use the frequency table results to recode each column from 0 to n with **the most frequent number** being equal to 0 and the remaining to 1,2,3 etc.

Here below what I was able to produce so far:

```
for (i in 1:((ncol(df) - 2)/2)){
  a = (1+i*2)
  b = (2+i*2)
  listMerged = c(df[,..a])
  listMerged = append(listMerged, c(df[,..b]))
  (squash_dbl(listMerged))->listMerged
  
  frequencies = sort(table(listMerged), decreasing = T)
  
  a=colnames(df)[a]
  b=colnames(df)[b]
  
  for (j in 1:length(frequencies)){
    df[, ..a][df[, ..a] == (names(frequencies)[j])] <- j-1
    df[, ..b][df[, ..b] == (names(frequencies)[j])] <- j-1
    
  }
  
}
```

The first loop works whereas in the second I get this error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , ..a, value = list(`01_OARCP49_1` = c(100,  : 
  object '..a' not found
```

My final output would be a database with the same structure as above but with recoded value (from 0 to n) for the columns 3:16 based on the frequency.

Here the expected output based for the two first columns on the example file:

```
 structure(list(breed = c("1", "1", "1"), id = c(1, 6, 12), `01_OARCP49_1` = c(1, 2, 0), `01_OARCP49_2` = c(3, 0, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Since: 82 is the most frequent value and it is set as 0. The remaining ones have same frequency and thus they are recoded from 1 till the last counted number.

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What is the output you expect/want based on the test data you have supplied?  There is probably an easier/quicker way to do it rather than running a loop, but from your description it's not easy to see what it might be...

Comment: @Limey Thank you for your reply! I just added in the body of the question what would be my expected output for example the 3rd and 4th column. Please let me know if something is still unclear!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution based on the tidyverse.

First, write a function to do the necessary calculation on a pair of adjacent columns.  The function's argument is the index of the first column in the data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

recodeDf <- function(x) {
  # Select the two columns of interest and pivot to long
  tmp <- df %>% 
           pivot_longer(c(x, x+1)) %>% 
           select(breed, id, name, value)
  # Calculate frequencies and assign "ranking" values
  newVals <- tmp %>% 
               group_by(value) %>% 
               summarise(N=n(), .groups="drop") %>% 
               arrange(desc(N), value) %>% 
               mutate(newValue=row_number()-1)
  # Recode and pivot wider
  tmp %>% 
    left_join(newVals, "value") %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from=name, values_from=newValue, id_cols=c(breed, id))
}
```

Test the function

```
recodeDf(3)
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  breed    id `01_OARCP49_1` `01_OARCP49_2`
  <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 1         1              2              3
2 1         6              1              0
3 1        12              0              4
```

This is slightly different to your expected output, but the ties in your test data make the correct answer ambiguous.  Are you sure your expected output is correct?  Or perhaps this is an acceptable alternative given the ties?

Now run the function over the entire data frame.  I've simplified the indexing that you used somewhat.

```
countList <- lapply(seq(3, 15, 2), recodeDf)
countList
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  breed    id `01_OARCP49_1` `01_OARCP49_2`
  <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 1         1              2              3
2 1         6              1              0
3 1        12              0              4

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  breed    id `02_FCB11_1` `02_FCB11_2`
  <chr> <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 1         1            0            0
2 1         6            1            1
3 1        12            0            2

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  breed    id `04_FCB304_1` `04_FCB304_2`
  <chr> <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 1         1             0             0
2 1         6             1             2
3 1        12             1             0

[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  breed    id `05_INRA063_1` `05_INRA063_2`
  <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 1         1              0              3
2 1         6              0              1
3 1        12              2              4

[[5]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  breed    id `06_MAF214_1` `06_MAF214_2`
  <chr> <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 1         1             0             0
2 1         6             1             0
3 1        12             0             2

[[6]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  breed    id `07_CSRD247_1` `07_CSRD247_2`
  <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 1         1              0              1
2 1         6              0              3
3 1        12              2              1

[[7]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  breed    id `08_HSC_1` `08_HSC_2`
  <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 1         1          1          1
2 1         6          0          0
3 1        12          0          2
```